# Why is this Lambda function async?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, aws-lambda

This Lambda function does an http-request and then writes the data into DynamoDB. I'm wondering why the function is set asynchronously. Wouldn't it be the same if it weren't async? As far as I know, await tells the code to pause and to continue after httprequest() is done. Isn't that the same like running the code synchronously?

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    try {
        const data = await httprequest();

        for (var i = 0; i < data.d.results.length; i++){
            var iden = Date.now();
            var identifier = iden.toString();
            datestring.substring(4,6) + "-" + datestring.substring(6,8);
            
        //add to dynamodb
        var params = {
            Item: {
                id: identifier,
                date: data.d.results[i].DAY_T,
            },
        TableName: 'DB'
        };
        await docClient.put(params).promise();
        }
        
        console.log('Document inserted.');
        return JSON.stringify(data);
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
        return err;
    }
};
```

Comment: Also, `await docClient`. --- To use await the function it is in needs to be async.

Comment: Not exaclty, no. `await` gives the JavaScript engine chance to run some other bit of JS rather than block waiting a response on the called function, just like promises.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await

Comment: *Isn't that the same like running the code synchronously* no, it's still async.

Answer (score 1):

async/await is syntactic sugar which makes *writing code* look similarly to how synchronous code would be written while maintaining all of the advantages of asynchronous code.

Essentially this:

```
var result = await doSomethingAsync();
console.log(result);
```

is actually this:

```
doSomethingAsync().then(result => {
    console.log(result);
});
```

If you imagine doing lots of this it gets heavily nested very quickly. When you include error handling too, the `then`/`catch` method gets long and verbose. async/await lets you use try/catch in a more natural way - the same way you're used to for synchronous code.

Mix in the fact that your code is doing multiple `await` within a loop, and I'd need to build up a list of promises and do a `Promise.all` there too. It all gets pretty hard to write without making a mistake.